What is the fundamental group of the space $X_n=SL(n, \mathbb{R})/SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$
The space of n dimensional unimodular lattices is often parametrised by the homogeneous space $$X_n=SL(n,\mathbb{R})/SL(n,\mathbb{Z}).$$ It is a manifold, as it is a quotient of a Lie group by a discrete subgroup. What is the fundamental group of $X_n$? I tried using the long exact sequence of fiber bundles, but that does not seem to be sufficient. Any help would be appreciated.

Have you tried describing the maps that appear in the long exact sequence to try to work it out? It looks like there's a plausible chance that could work, since the fundamental group of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ is just $\mathbb{Z}$ for $n = 2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2$ otherwise.

Let $H(n):=\pi_1(SL(n))$, i.e. $H(n)=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ for $n\geq3$, $H(2)=\mathbb Z$, $H(1)=1$, and let $G(n)$ be the 1-connected Lie group covering $SL(n,\mathbb R)$. We thus have a central extension
$$H(n)\to G(n)\to SL(n,\mathbb R).$$
Finally, let $K(n)$ be the preimage of $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ under the projection $G(n)\to SL(n,\mathbb R)$, i.e. we have a central extension (of discrete groups)
$$H(n)\to K(n)\to SL(n,\mathbb Z).\quad(*)$$
Since $SL(n,\mathbb R)/SL(n,\mathbb Z)=G(n)/K(n)$ and since $G(n)$ is 1-connected and $K(n)\subset G(n)$ discrete,
$$\pi_1(SL(n,\mathbb R)/SL(n,\mathbb Z))=K(n).$$
(You might want to know more about that central extension $(*)$ to fully understand $K(n)$, either in terms of a cocycle or in terms of generators and relations, but unfortunately I don't know (maybe with the exception of $n=2$), so perhaps this is not quite an answer, but it doesn't quite fit to a comment.)
